# Is there a quick way to add Unit Scope to my Delphi units?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

We're in the process of moving out Delphi XE2 apps over to Delphi XE5 (We have a window :) )

I'm wondering whether, as part of the move, I should be thinkning of adding my own Unit Scope to our internal applications.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705802/what-is-the-recommended-naming-for-scoped-units-in-delphi-xe2-onwards) question suggests that it's just of case of renaming units as *Company.Unit*.

Is it as simple as using *Rename* in the Project Manager?

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nearly that simple. You can use the *Rename* action in the project manager and that will rename the file, give the unit a new name, and change references in the .dpr and .dproj file. But that will not rename any references in code.

So, if you list the unit in `uses` clauses (seems likely that you will), or use the unit name to resolve ambiguous scope, then you will need to change the names there too.

If you don't have too many units it won't be very difficult to make the change in the project manager, and then fix all the errors that the compiler throws at you. If you have a larger project then you may be better scripting the change. I expect that you could go 99% of the way there with a simple regex based script that did the following:

1. Update references in the .dpr and .dproj files.
2. Change the file names and the unit names.
3. Find the uses clauses (interface and implementation sections) and update references there.

This would leave you to deal with the uses that perform scope resolution and my guess is that there would be few enough of these to let the compiler find them all.

Comment: Cheers!  Seems a bit crazy that the rename doesn't hit the *uses* clauses... also seems crazy that your can't refactor > rename the uses...

Answer (score 2):

I use a great Tool from http://www.easy-ip.net (DELPHI UNIT DEPENDENCY SCANNER) for that task.
You can change the Name of the unit and the DUPS change all your uses clause's.